# How to depict different categories on a table?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, user-centered-design, product-design

So the user will have to add a department and choose one of the two categories for the department. What is the best way to depict on a table what category the department belongs to?

Option 1

[image]

Option 2

[image]

Option 3

[image]

Comment: "...the user will have to add a department and choose one of the two categories for the department." Is user selection pertinent to your question? Or are you only looking for best ways to present the departments and categories?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the "SL No." column is important and has relevance to this display, option 1 has the greatest separation for distinguishing between the two categories - the grouping implies separateness more than any of the other options (try googling 'principles of grouping' if you need any further information about how that works).

Option 2 has the lowest separation - at a glance, it's very difficult to see a difference between category 1 and 2 list items.

Option 3 looks like it should be a middle ground at first, but it relies on colour to differentiate so may not be as visible to every user.

If, on the other hand, the "SL No." column isn't important then you could simply group the two categories into separate sections, tables, tabs, or even pages depending on the context within your architecture.

Another option could be to offer a filter to help the user to refine the table to a single category.

However, as with anything here on UX StackExchange, you should really test with your users under the conditions that they will be using the UI.